# Checksum of SELECT results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, checksum

Trying to get a check sum of results of a SELECT statement, tried this

```
SELECT sum(crc32(column_one))
FROM database.table;
```

Which worked, but this did not work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(sum(crc32(column_one)),sum(crc32(column_two)))
FROM database.table;
```

Open to suggestions, main idea is to get a valid checksum for the SUM of the results of rows and columns from a SELECT statement.

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? Error messages? Unexpected result? Server crashed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `CONCAT` and `SUM` are not compatible in this format.

`CONCAT` is designed to run once per row in your result set on the arguments as defined by that row.

`SUM` is an aggregate function, designed to run on a full result set.

`CRC32` is of the same class of functions as `CONCAT`.

So, you've got functions nested in a way that just don't play nicely together.

You could try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    (SELECT sum(crc32(column_one)) FROM database.table),
    (SELECT sum(crc32(column_two)) FROM database.table)
);
```

or

```
SELECT sum(crc32(column_one)), sum(crc32(column_two))
FROM database.table;
```

and concatenate them with your client language.

Comment: Please always keep in mind for your large tables of "Expected collisions"  
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210379/1896134  Which potentially could give you a `false positive`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CRC32(CONCAT(column_one, column_two)))
FROM database.table;
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(CRC32(column_one) + CRC32(column_two))
FROM database.table;
```