# get checksum of a specific number of rows

Tags: mysql

I know it's possible to get checksum for a table like so:

`CHECKSUM TABLE table_name`

I would like to, however, get the checksum for a specific # of rows. For instance:

`CHECKSUM TABLE table_name LIMIT 0, 10000`

To check just the first 10,000 rows. I know you can calculate the checksum of a specific column,  or calculate multiple columns and add them together, but that seems like a hassle. Is there any other method to do this?

The purpose for this is to verify that 2 tables (on different servers) are the same, and to find out at which point they become different.

Comment: I had a similar requirement I used this answer
`sum(crc32(column_one))`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955776/checksum-of-select-results-in-mysql

Comment: i guess i will implement that solution. thanks